# Query pulling 12-15 GB data From more than 120 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I have a query which is pulling data from almost 125 different tables, I have created some 13 nested Stored Procedures calling other stored procedures to pull all the required data. Surprise Surprise Surprise The query takes ages to execute and sometimes I have to kill he connection and rerun it.

I have been advised to make use of staging table, Move required data there using SSIS packages and pull data from there, but I am a bit reluctant to use SSIS as Im not very comfortable with SSIS and This report is requested once in a while and also moving around 10-15 gb data for one report seems a lot of hassle.

Any suggestion any ideas please to make this hell of task a bit simpler, quicker and less error prone ???

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you John as you can see this is my 1st question ever on this blog. :)

Comment: Sounds like you have a serious modeling problem. Here is my two cents I would definitely use staging or temp tables and stay away from SSIS. SSIS IMHO is more for non devs and if you are comfortable the T-SQL stay with it. I myself do ETL processes by hand and find it more flexible. If this is a production DB that causes client issues you might want to move the raw data first as is to another DB the do your ETL from there. If that is possible then you can add indices that are design exclusively around this process therefore increasing overall performance. Good Luck

Comment: @MuhammedAli: FYI, this is not a blog. Please read the [faq].

Comment: I would never dare to run such a report on a production server, I have a separate server purely for reporting purposes, I have lost count of the number of Temp tables I have used in all the stored procedures pulling all this data.

Comment: I would never dare to run such a report on a production server, I have a separate server purely for reporting purposes, I have lost count of the number of Temp tables I have used in all the stored procedures pulling all this data.  I was advised to denormalize data and use staging table to store that denormalized data. But like I have mentioned before this report is requested once in a while only for One or maybe two clients. Denormalization of data and storing separately for all clients seems a lot of work for one report which I might never need.

Comment: I am looking for any solution which will make this task a little bit simpler, quicker and easier to maintain, I think I am pushing my luck here but you never know :)

Comment: You're looking for a silver bullet where there is none.  Sometimes work is just hard.

Comment: I guess you'er right and I dont mind hard work mate but right now performance is my biggest issue. I will be a happy bunny if I could get this job done even in half an hour but right now it takes me 3-4 hours and sometimes many failed attempts when I have to kill the connection because it had taking almost 5 hours and literally bring down server to its knees.

Answer (score 1):

Create a reporting database. On some frequency, be that hourly, daily, or whatever frequency meets the needs of the reports users, ETL the data from the transactional database into the reporting database.

You can use SSIS or you could choose to execute some stored procedures for ETL. Regardless, you probably will schedule it with a SQL Agent Job.

Finally, in terms of designing your report database, consider transforming the data in a way that will help the reports performance. Many people "flatten" or de-normalize data for the purpose of reporting. We ETL transactional data into a data warehouse that uses the "star schema" pattern and we also have an Analysis Services Database and MDX Reports as well. Most likely you don't need to go that far for one report, but, that is further down this same path of optimized data structures for reporting and BI.

Comment: Cheers pal thanks for suggestions but as I have mentioned in my question I am aware of these choices, I was looking for a simpler or easier way to achieve this since I am not to comfortable with SSIS and my manager has dumped this report on me. I have passed this on to my DW team and they are looking into it as frankly speaking its not a ONE MAN job :) anyway I appreciate your effort pal.

Comment: Sorry to pile on but I thought the numbers might help your case with management. If you have a DW Team, you did the right thing and this is definitely a job for them.

Comment: DW team at my place are a bunch of ********* if you know what I mean :). The job is still on the Log queue no one has accepted it yet but its off my back. I have put on the job log "in small very small print" that I will help whoever does the job. But we'll see when we got to that stage lolll