# Get Connection's IP Address in SQL Server without VIEW SERVER STATE permission?

Tags: sql-server, ip-address

Is there a way to get the IP Address of a connection without the user being in the SysAdmin Role or being granted VIEW SERVER STATE? One of these is required to issue this query:

```
select client_net_address from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id = @@spid
```

I want to log the IP Address inside an Instead-Of Trigger, but I don't want to go granting the VIEW SERVER STATE permission to all users.

Thanks for any suggestions.

---

Followup 2013-10-05:
Thanks for the various comments. What are the dangers in granting VIEW SERVER STATE to all users?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the trigger to execute as owner:

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.whatever_instead
ON dbo.whatever
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.log_table(column1, ...)
  SELECT client_net_address, ...
    FROM sys.dm_exec_connections 
    WHERE session_id = @@SPID;

  ... other stuff here I'm sure ...
END
GO
```

However, by default, you should get the following error:

> Msg 15562, Level 16, State 1, Procedure whatever_instead
>   
>  The module being executed is not trusted. Either the owner of the database of the module needs to be granted authenticate permission, or the module needs to be digitally signed.
>   The statement has been terminated.

One way to work around this is to set your database to [`TRUSTWORTHY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187861.aspx):

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
```

Do not take this setting lightly:

- [Guidelines for using the TRUSTWORTHY database setting in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2183687)
- [The TRUSTWORTHY Database Property Explained – Part 1](http://sqlity.net/en/1653/the-trustworthy-database-property-explained-part-1/)

Comment: Thanks. It appears that I need TRUSTWORTHY ON in order to use CLR UDFs.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Some_Proc
WITH EXECUTE AS 'User_With_Permission'
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        select client_net_address from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id = @@spid
END
```

Call this proc from your trigger

Comment: This still yields error 15562 unless the module is signed or the database is set to trustworthy. So encapsulating it in a stored procedure is an extra and unnecessary step.

Comment: even if we grant GRANT **IMPERSONATE ON LOGIN::[login_to_be_impersonated] to [login1];**

Comment: Did you try that? Can you include some code that demonstrates it works?

Comment: Opss I have just tried it myself and it didnt work and Im sorry to try to argue with you :D just seen your profile now. Well I guess at least I have learnt something after putting up this post. Thanks Aaron :)

Comment: float like a butterfly, sting like a bee

Comment: Aaron I posted a question few days ago and I havent got any really helpful answer would you please mind looking at it and see if you could suggest something please pal.....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071630/query-pulling-12-15-gb-data-from-more-than-120-tables